# Django optimized queryset

Tags: sql, django, optimization

I am trying to do that :

```
emails = [c.email for c in Client.objects.all().order_by('lastname', 'firstname')]
```

Is there a better way to do that so it would query `SELECT email from clients ORDER BY lastname, firstname` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Client.objects.order_by('lastname', 'firstname').values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Comment: If you're going to want the list (vs. just an iterator), as it appears you do in your example, then you should wrap the above in a list() call, because it's more efficient on the DB side of things.

Comment: Why would that be more efficient? By casting `ValuesListQuerySet` to list you're performing the same database call as you would by iterating through it's contents. There's no change in the DB communication.